# ODE transformation for Midpoint Implicit method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to transform my ODE to an update scheme for the midpoint implicit method and I can't get the right answer.

The ODE is $\frac{du}{dt} = -3t^2(u-2)$

Which I think means $f(u(t),t) = -3t^2(u-2)$

The initial condition is $u(0) = 2.18$ although that's not too important for the context of this question.

The equation for the midpoint implicit method is $u_{i+1} = u_i + hf(\frac{1}{2}(u_i+u_{i+1}),t_i+\frac{h}{2})$

I think I need $u_{i+1}$ in terms of $h$, $t_i$ and $u_i$ without the function $f$ being there anymore but I can't do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you parametrize $u_{i+1}=u_i+2k$, then you get the equation
$$
k=\frac{h}2f(u_i+k,t_i+\frac h2)
$$
which you could recognize as an implicit Euler step. So if you have methods to solve that, or just use this equation in a Newton method or similar to solve for $k$, you also get a solver for the midpoint method.

---

In this specific case as the ODE is linear in $u$ this equation can be solved directly as
$$
(1+\tfrac32ht_{i+1/2}^2)k=-\tfrac32ht_{i+1/2}^2(u_i-2),~~~t_{i+1/2}=t_i+\frac h2,
$$
so that
$$
u_{i+1}=u_i-\frac{3ht_{i+1/2}^2}{1+\tfrac32ht_{i+1/2}^2}(u_i-2)
=2+\frac{1-\tfrac32ht_{i+1/2}^2}{1+\tfrac32ht_{i+1/2}^2}(u_i-2).
$$